# Dynamically Create NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, rest, xcode4

I have a need to be able to create the `NSFetchedResultsController` dynamically, and am curious if this is even possible. The basis for this is that I need to be able to fetch results based on a variable. To my understanding I would need multiple NSFRCs to handle the multiple requests (it will be a `UISegmentControl TableView`). The problem being I don't know how many controllers I will need as it is variable depending on what my API returns.

Is there a better method for this, could I not just pass a variable to NSFRC as the predicate?

Looking for best options to handle this.

An example would be:

I have 13 different status' for jobs (Open, On Hold, Cancelled, etc), fetching all jobs then running the filter would tremendously slow down the application returning ~ 50K records.

So my though was to fetch the status' use the status as a predicate and then fetch from the API jobs of that status.

What is my best approach?

Comment: You don't want to have a different section for each status? Yes, you can have a method where you pass the fetch request and it creates the FRC.

Comment: you can even have multiple NSFetchResultsController working on the same tableview (lets say having one by section)

Comment: Yeah I know I can have multiple, the issue is, I don't know how many are going to be needed until I do the first request for the status'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `NSFetchRequest` of an `NSFetchedResultsController` without problems. There is a special section in the documentation about this topic. If you use a cache, you need to delete it, afterwards you can change your fetch request and call `performFetch:` again, on your `NSFetchedResultsController`. The trick is to *modify* the existing `NSFetchRequest` on your controller instead of trying to set a new fetch request, which will not work.

In your case, you might want to set the predicate of the fetch request by calling `-[NSFetchRequest setPredicate:]`

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName];
[self.controller.fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", currentStatus]];
NSError* error = nil;
if (![self.controller performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error updating fetch: %@", error);
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: So this would be triggered by the UISegmentControl ?

Comment: Yes, if you change your filters with a UISegmentedControl this would be in the action the control triggers.

Comment: this worked great thank you! One thing however, if one of my results returns 0 sections, and then the filtering to another returns 0, I'm getting a crash, saying that it can't delete 0 sections of 0 sections. I understand why it's happening just not sure how to address it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is the exact error "attempt to delete section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update"

Comment: Who is causing the delete? Is this triggered by the fetched results controller delegate?